# Sum SQL timestamp

Tags: mysql, sql

How can do a sum search by 'id=1' and add up their hours.
The first line will be there in time, the next will be their out time.

Below should add up to 5:43:29

```
id, ts
1,2016-06-20 04:25:32
3,2016-06-20 07:40:09
1,2016-06-20 09:37:46
3,2016-06-20 14:40:57
1,2016-06-20 15:12:14
1,2016-06-20 15:43:29
2,2016-06-20 15:47:01
2,2016-06-20 17:47:03
```

Comment: `sum(hour(ts)) group by id`? of course, handling the record cross-over business will be the hard part.

Comment: How do you get `5:43:29`? `09:37:46 - 04:25:32` is `05:12:14`.

Answer (score 0):

Oh boy, this was a fun one:

```
SELECT SEC_TO_TIME(
    SUM(UNIX_TIMESTAMP(
        (SELECT ts FROM example_table e2 WHERE id = ranked.id AND ts > ranked.ts ORDER BY id, ts LIMIT 1)
    )-UNIX_TIMESTAMP(ts))
)
FROM ( 
    SELECT 
        @row := @row +1 AS rownum, id, ts
    FROM ( 
        SELECT @row :=0) r, example_table
    WHERE id = 1
    ORDER BY id ASC, ts ASC
    ) ranked 
WHERE ranked.rownum % 2 = 1
```

First we fetch all the odd rows: 1, 3, 5, 7 and soforth. Next, we use a subquery to fetch the next timestamp matching that row (The punch out time), and get the differences (In seconds). Sum will total up the seconds, and sec_to_time will convert that into a friendly readable format.

Answer (score 0):

You can add row number with user defined variable. Here odd rows represents starting time, multiply -1 when it is starting time with `if(r%2=0,1,-1)`, and add them up:

```
select sec_to_time(sum(time_to_sec(ts)*if(r%2=0,1,-1)))
from (
  select @row:=@row+1 r, a.*
  from Table1 a
  join (select @row:=0) b
  where a.id = 1) a;
```

Answer (score 0):

Here my answer with a sample

Use sql like this:

```
SELECT
  t_from.id,
  SEC_TO_TIME(SUM(TIME_TO_SEC( TIMEDIFF(
    ( SELECT ts 
      FROM t t_to
      WHERE
        t_to.ts > t_from.ts_from
      AND
        t_to.id = t_from.id
      ORDER BY t_to.id,t_to.ts
      LIMIT 1
    )
    ,  t_from.ts_from
   )))) AS ts_diff
FROM (
  SELECT @nr:=((@nr+1) %2) AS nr,t.id,t.ts AS ts_from
  FROM t
  CROSS JOIN ( SELECT @nr:=0) AS parameter
  ORDER BY id
) AS t_from
WHERE nr =1
GROUP BY t_from.id;
```

**my Table**

```
MariaDB [yourSchema]> select * from t;
+----+---------------------+
| id | ts                  |
+----+---------------------+
|  1 | 2016-06-20 04:25:32 |
|  3 | 2016-06-20 07:40:09 |
|  1 | 2016-06-20 09:37:46 |
|  3 | 2016-06-20 14:40:57 |
|  1 | 2016-06-20 15:12:14 |
|  1 | 2016-06-20 15:43:29 |
|  2 | 2016-06-20 15:47:01 |
|  2 | 2016-06-20 17:47:03 |
+----+---------------------+
8 rows in set (0.00 sec)
```

**convert to start end times**

```
MariaDB [yourSchema]> SELECT
    ->   t_from.id
    ->   , t_from.ts_from,
    ->   ( SELECT ts
    ->       FROM t t_to
    ->       WHERE
    ->         t_to.ts > t_from.ts_from
    ->       AND
    ->         t_to.id = t_from.id
    ->       ORDER BY t_to.id,t_to.ts
    ->       LIMIT 1
    ->     )  AS ts_to
    -> FROM (
    ->   SELECT @nr:=((@nr+1) %2) AS nr,t.id,t.ts AS ts_from
    ->   FROM t
    ->   CROSS JOIN ( SELECT @nr:=0) AS parameter
    ->   ORDER BY id
    -> ) AS t_from
    -> WHERE nr =1;
+----+---------------------+---------------------+
| id | ts_from             | ts_to               |
+----+---------------------+---------------------+
|  1 | 2016-06-20 04:25:32 | 2016-06-20 09:37:46 |
|  1 | 2016-06-20 15:12:14 | 2016-06-20 15:43:29 |
|  2 | 2016-06-20 15:47:01 | 2016-06-20 17:47:03 |
|  3 | 2016-06-20 07:40:09 | 2016-06-20 14:40:57 |
+----+---------------------+---------------------+
4 rows in set (0.00 sec)

MariaDB [yourSchema]>
```

**Sum the diffs and group by id**

```
MariaDB [yourSchema]> SELECT
    ->   t_from.id,
    ->   SEC_TO_TIME(SUM(TIME_TO_SEC( TIMEDIFF(
    ->     ( SELECT ts
    ->       FROM t t_to
    ->       WHERE
    ->         t_to.ts > t_from.ts_from
    ->       AND
    ->         t_to.id = t_from.id
    ->       ORDER BY t_to.id,t_to.ts
    ->       LIMIT 1
    ->     )
    ->     ,  t_from.ts_from
    ->    )))) AS ts_diff
    -> FROM (
    ->   SELECT @nr:=((@nr+1) %2) AS nr,t.id,t.ts AS ts_from
    ->   FROM t
    ->   CROSS JOIN ( SELECT @nr:=0) AS parameter
    ->   ORDER BY id
    -> ) AS t_from
    -> WHERE nr =1
    -> GROUP BY t_from.id;
+----+----------+
| id | ts_diff  |
+----+----------+
|  1 | 05:43:29 |
|  2 | 02:00:02 |
|  3 | 07:00:48 |
+----+----------+
3 rows in set (0.00 sec)

MariaDB [yourSchema]>
```

Answer (score 0):

Join the table with itself and search for the next timestamp:

```sql
select t1.id,
    t1.ts as ts_from,
    min(t2.ts) as ts_to,
    timediff(min(t2.ts), t1.ts) as uptime
from uptime t1
join uptime t2
    on  t2.id = t1.id
    and t2.ts > t1.ts
where t1.id = 1
group by t1.id, t1.ts
```

Result:

```sql
| id |             ts_from |               ts_to |   uptime |
|----|---------------------|---------------------|----------|
|  1 | 2016-06-20 04:25:32 | 2016-06-20 09:37:46 | 05:12:14 |
|  1 | 2016-06-20 09:37:46 | 2016-06-20 15:12:14 | 05:34:28 |
|  1 | 2016-06-20 15:12:14 | 2016-06-20 15:43:29 | 00:31:15 |
```

[Demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/7193d5/1)

You will need an index on `id, ts`.

```sql
ALTER TABLE `uptime` ADD INDEX `id_ts` (`id`, `ts`);
```

**Update:**

After reading you question again i think i got what you are after. You can use the obove query in a subquery, a session variable to switch betwen even and odd rows and a conditional SUM:

```sql
select sec_to_time(sum(
    case when @switch := 1 - @switch then time_to_sec(sub.uptime) end
)) as uptime
from (
    select timediff(min(t2.ts), t1.ts) as uptime
    from uptime t1
    join uptime t2
        on  t2.id = t1.id
        and t2.ts > t1.ts
    where t1.id = 1
    group by t1.id, t1.ts
    order by t1.ts
) sub
join (select @switch := 0) init_switch
```

[Demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/7193d5/5)